# Session Sharing react/express

Tags: reactjs, session, express, express-session

So,I have already set up an express server and passport for facebook auth.However if I serve react with nginx in  a different server than express how would it be possible to share session data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your React app proxy to a route on your Express server, which will call `req.isAuthenticated()`.

`isAuthenticated()` will return true/false depending on if the user is logged in.